# Why am I getting an unsupported operand type error?

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I am new to programming and am learning Python. I am trying to build a simple program and am receiving a typeerror on line 9 of my code.

I would expect that "potearned" and "curpart" are both floats, so that they would be able to be divided. Why can't I divide these two variables?

I've tried changing the data type of a few variables in the code to no avail. Most recently I've tried using the float() function to convert the operands to floating point numbers, but this did not work.

The code I am writing is:

```
`begpart = input("How many participants started the game?")
curpart = input("How many participants are there left?")
bet = raw_input("How much did you bet?")
cutper = input(" What is stepbet's cut? (as decimal)")
float(cutper)
potearned = (begpart - curpart) * bet
float(curpart)
float(potearned)
earnper = potearned / curpart   <------------ error line, line 9
cut = earnper
cut = earnper * cutper
float(cut)
pot = begpart * bet
float(pot)
print cut
print earnper
netearn = earnper - cut
print netearn
netearns = str(netearn)'

print "If noone else drops out you will earn " + netearns
```

My expected result is for the entire program to run without hitting a typeerror. What is happening when I execute the program is I am receiving the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int' "
```

Answer (score 0):

`float(cutpart)` and other such lines do not convert the existing `cutpart` to a float; they return a new version of `cutpart` that is a float. You're throwing the returned float out though by not saving it to a variable. Change that line (and other such lines) to:

```
cutpart = float(cutpart)
```

Or, to be proper, give it a new name so you can still reference the previous version of `pot` if need be:

```
float_cutpart = float(cutpart)
float_potearned = float(potearned)
earnper = float_cutpart / float_potearned
```